# How does review work?

Tags: support, reputation, review, badges

I would like to know how the review system works.

I guess the minimum reputation required for a review task is 500 or 2000, but I have seen many Stack Overflow accounts with less reputation which have the [*Custodian* badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/188732#188732). Can someone explain me this? I have attached an image below.

[image: Custodian badge]

As you can see, this account only has 3 reputation points with three badges. How are they allowed to submit a review? I currently have 492 reputation points and I can't see the option to review in my account.

Am I missing something?

Comment: They might have approved/rejected a suggested edit on their own question or answer

Comment: How can I do that in my own post?

Comment: @VirajD you'd get notified. *e.g. XXX made a edit to your post: go check it*